# Object not persisting

Tags: matlab, object, constructor, destructor, matlab-class

In the following piece of code, the destructor of class `TdcTestResult` is called at the end of function `add`, and so method variable `mTdcTestResults` will become empty again.

How can I make the instance of `TdcTestResult` inside `mTdcTestResults` persistent?

```
classdef Tdc

    properties % (Access = private)
        mTestRun     = TdcTestRun;
        mTestResults = [];
    end

    methods(Access = public)

        function add(obj, componentSerialNumber, testName, testVersion, paramName, unitOfMeasureCode, paramScale, paramLimitTypeCode, paramLowerLimit, paramUpperLimit, responseValue, folderPath, isFailed, isOverridden, overriddenReason)
            if(nargin > 0)
                obj.mTestResults = [obj.mTestResults TdcTestResult];
                obj.mTestResults(end).set(componentSerialNumber, testName, testVersion, paramName, unitOfMeasureCode, paramScale, paramLimitTypeCode, paramLowerLimit, paramUpperLimit, responseValue, folderPath, isFailed, isOverridden, overriddenReason);

                obj.mTestRun.addTestResult(obj.mTestResults(end));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: In the explanation above the code, do you mean `mTestResults` instead of `mTdcTestResults`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the actual issue is that you're effectively not changing `obj`.
If you would, the reference to the new `TdcTestResult` inside `mTestResults` should prevent the destructor from being called.

This is connected to Danial R's answer:
If you don't implement `Tdc` as a `handle` subclass, your `add` method has to return the modified `obj`.
Otherwise the changed you make inside `add` are lost.

So you'll either have to return `obj` and modify your calling syntax to

```
tdcObject = tdcObject.add(...);
```

or inherit from `handle` - which is probably the better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

`TdcTestResult` needs `handle` to be a superclass, otherwise your code can not work. More details in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/handle.html)

If this does not help, please include an executable example of code.